# Qt Login Dialog Box before Main Window

Tags: qt, user-interface, authentication, dialog

How do I have the user first login before getting to the main window in my QT app? I'm new to QT and have looked through the documentation and have not found anything very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I would make this in the following way. Let's assume, that my login dialog is a `QDialog`:

```
class Login : public QDialog
{
    [..]
};
```

In my application, I create an instance of my Login dialog and if it is accepted, i.e. closed with OK button, I open my main window:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    [..]
    QMainWindow mw;
    Login login;
    if (login.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        mw.show();
    }
    [..]
}
```

Comment: You should declare `mw` outside the if block. Unless it will get destroyed when exiting the block.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    LoginWindow l;                                     // create login-widget
    connect(&l, SIGNAL(loggedIn), &w, SLOT(show());    // connect to mainwindow show()
    l.show();                                          // show login-window instead of
                                                       // mainwindow at start
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You should also provide some explanations to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to :

1 - exec the loop only if the dialog is accepted, otherwise you application continues to run

2 - create the mainwindow only if accepted, cause it might be a heavy interface, which takes time to initialize

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Dialog_Login dialog;
  if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
    MainWindow w;
    w.setUser(dialog.GetUser());
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

You need to create the QApplication instance in parrallel with the login dialog.